# Замена вхождений в тексте по регулярке

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Есть php-переменная `$html` в которой какой-то html, а в нём встречаются вхождения типа `{PHRASE=1}`, `{PHRASE=2}`, `{PHRASE=N}`. Эти вхождения необходимо заменять соответствующими фразами из БД mySQL по их id, т.е. `{PHRASE=5}` должно замениться на фразу с id=5 и текстом "Фраза номер пять", и так далее.

Пишу функцию. Вот до чего я дошёл сам:

```
    function rewriteHtml($html) {

    $phrase = 'PHRASE';

    if (mb_strpos($html, $phrase) === false){
    // если слово PHRASE в тексте переменной не встречается, то всё понятно
        $new_html = $html;

    } else {

     // а вот если встречается, то тут надо составить какую-то регулярку, и по ней как-то отыскать айдишники, а уж дальше я необходимые форазы из БД вытащу))  
        $new_html = ??????????;

    } 

    return $new_html;
}
```

В регулярках вообще не силён, и плохо представляю дальнейший алгоритм работы.

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С использованием регулярных выражений для поиска числовых `ID`решение будет, например, таким:

Исходные данные

```
$html = <<< HTML
<a href="#">{phrase=1}</a>
<p>{phrase=2}<strong>{phrase=3}<srong></p>
<b>{phrase=2}</b>
HTML;
```

Извлечение уникальных значений

```
if(preg_match_all("/{phrase=(\d+)}/", $html, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)){
    $ids = array_unique($matches[1]);
    print_r($ids);
}
```

где флаг `PREG_PATTER_ORDER` определяет, что в `matches[1]` будут содержаться значения всех первых групп, а `array_unique` получает только уникальные идентификаторы из найденных.

Answer (score 0):

можно и так

```
for($i=1; $i < count($data); $i++) {
   str_replace('PHRASE_' . $i, $data[$i-1]);
}
```

где `data` это данные вытащеные с базы с соответственными id.

Comment: а если в базе миллион id, а на странице встречаются только 10?